# how to make div stick to bottom of overflow:auto parent div?

Tags: css, css-position

A slight twist on the common question of sticking a div to the bottom of a parent div.  In this case I want the stuck div to STAY stuck even when it's parent is scrolled, and to be on top of the text that scrolls underneath.  What's the trick?  jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/vYjMv/1/.  code repeated below:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #wrapper {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#eee;
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;
      }

      .bot {
        border:1px solid #ddd;
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        color:blue;
      }

    </style>
    <title>tst</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed tempor nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec molestie tortor non nisi accumsan placerat. Morbi elit risus, venenatis et sodales congue, tristique vel ligula. Maecenas convallis arcu turpis. Praesent nibh leo, blandit ut posuere et, aliquet at sapien. Ut placerat, libero id faucibus pellentesque, leo nulla consectetur ligula, quis malesuada sapien nulla id diam. Nullam turpis nisl, malesuada non gravida eu, eleifend et quam. Proin sit amet elit euismod odio tincidunt tempor. Sed eleifend tincidunt blandit. Cras eget sapien odio, a sodales dui. Pellentesque tincidunt varius sagittis. Nullam nisl est, volutpat sed fringilla at, faucibus id mi. Phasellus vel lacus nibh, eget consectetur nulla. Quisque vel elementum nibh. Etiam vitae lectus erat, eu euismod est.
      </p>
      <span class="bot">bottom</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put another new div same width & height of warpper and stuck div to it:

check this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       #fake_wrapper{
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:none;
      }

      #wrapper {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#eee;
        overflow:auto;
      }

      .bot {
        border:1px solid #ddd;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        right:15px;
        color:blue;
      }

    </style>
    <title>tst</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fake_wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed tempor nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec molestie tortor non nisi accumsan placerat. Morbi elit risus, venenatis et sodales congue, tristique vel ligula. Maecenas convallis arcu turpis. Praesent nibh leo, blandit ut posuere et, aliquet at sapien. Ut placerat, libero id faucibus pellentesque, leo nulla consectetur ligula, quis malesuada sapien nulla id diam. Nullam turpis nisl, malesuada non gravida eu, eleifend et quam. Proin sit amet elit euismod odio tincidunt tempor. Sed eleifend tincidunt blandit. Cras eget sapien odio, a sodales dui. Pellentesque tincidunt varius sagittis. Nullam nisl est, volutpat sed fringilla at, faucibus id mi. Phasellus vel lacus nibh, eget consectetur nulla. Quisque vel elementum nibh. Etiam vitae lectus erat, eu euismod est.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="bot">bottom fixed</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this one](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/vYjMv/3/).

Made the `position: fixed` of `.bot` and added a `top` and `left`.